# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogBasicFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I've changed my project's setting to use the 'mix & match' (use Objective-c and Swift either in the same project).
So, I added a line 'use_frameworks!' in pod files and installed the pods. After that, Application is crashed by runtime error as below.

> dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogBasicFormatter
>        Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1FAFE24C-C0E8-4057-A503-E4912B7115E6/MyApplication.app/MyApplication
>        Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1FAFE24C-C0E8-4057-A503-E4912B7115E6/MyApplication.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac
>       in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1FAFE24C-C0E8-4057-A503-E4912B7115E6/MyApplication.app/MyApplication

To resolve this, I've tried to change pod file so many times.
When I remove " pod 'Firebase/core' " written in-app extension target, the `dyld` error does not occur.

I think as `Firebase/Core` is contained in three targets (**application**, **app** and **extension**), duplicate `GoogleToolBoxForMac` is created, and it makes the error. How can I resolve this?

[error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uiiz7.png)

[pod target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsKZa.png)

[framework target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDWYD.png)

Comment: Any solution to this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @FerdinandRios Add " pod 'GoogleUtilities' " in your pod file. –